# Excel row aggregation by index

Tags: excel

Need to group rows with using an index and at the same time adding a numerical column and joining a text with a dash character. I'll go straight to an example to save on words

What I have:

```
Index   Value   Text
A        10    Text1
A        10    Text2
B        20    Text3
C        30    Text4
B        20    Text5
B        5     Text6
```

What is needed:

```
Index   Value   Text
A        20     Text1-Text2
B        45     Text3-Text5-Text6
C        30     Text4
```

Comment: Yes it is, as long as each row remains the same

Comment: ok, what is the correct search term for this kind of query? I "did" search (seriously) but found nothing

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 or Office365 you can use the [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c), otherwise this would need VBA.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you open to using R?  This would be easy with the dplyr library:
df <- data.frame(Index=c("A","A","B","C","B","B"),
                 Value=c(10,10,20,30,20,5),
                 Text=c("Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5","Text6"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Index) %>% 
  summarise(Value=sum(Value),
            Text=paste0(Text, collapse = "-"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2010 or later, you can do this with `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform` in Excel 2016)

After you select the data and open the Power Query Editor, select to

- Group By Index and choose to Sum the Value column, and also an `All Rows` aggregation

[image]

- The third column will then be a column of "Tables".

[image]

- Add a Custom colum to convert the new `myTable` column into a `List`.  Note the formula that accomplishes the task

[image]

- Delete the `myTable` column
- from the new Custom column select to Extract the values.
  [image]
- A dialog box will open allowing you to specify the delimiter

[image]

The query can be saved and used on future data.

[image]

Comment: Just awesome, thank you. Your answer is pretty unique and useful, avoiding VB code...

Answer (score 0):

For me, easier to repeat YET again (though with *slight* twists) than to find a dupe master:

1. Sort on the `Index` column (assumed here to be ColumnA ... we are talking spreadsheets here - they have CELL REFERENCES for a reason!)
2. In D2 (assuming labels are in Row1!) and copied down to suit:

   `=IF(A1=A2,D1&"-"&C2,C2)`
3. Subtotal At each change in: `Index`, Use function: `Sum`, Add subtotal to: `Value` (only) with Summary below data.
4. Filter to select `Index` contains `Total` and in first blank cell below D1 insert and copy down to suit:

   `=INDIRECT("D"&ROW()-1)`
5. Clear Filter, Select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.
6. Filter to select `Index` does not contain `Total` and delete all but header row.
7. Remove Filter, Remove All subtotals, move C1 to D1, delete ColumnC and in ColumnA Replace `Total` by nothing.